# C# Nested IFs OR and condition?

Tags: c#, if-statement

Which one is better? performance wise and best practice wise. and why?

```
if ((process_checking == true) && (standard_output.Contains("0")))
{
}
else if ((process_checking == true) && (standard_output.Contains("1")))
{
}
```

OR

```
if (process_checking==true)
{
   if (standard_output.Contains("0"))
   {
     blah
   }
   else
    //there is only 0 or 1 value
   {
      blah
   }
}
```

Comment: better in terms of? Performance, readability, maintenance?

Comment: also if there is just 0 or 1 value, then no need of `Contains()`

Comment: performance wise and best practice wise

Comment: Why dont you just benchmark it?

Comment: @Praveen. it is checking a string which has 0 or 1. so I need the "contains"

Comment: COMMENT: I don't understand why this question get 5 (so far) thumbs down? Is this too easy?Is the question not clear? Aren't we all learning here ??

Comment: @JohnRyann First, your question is still a bit unclear. You did not describe any problem encountered and then you ask for performance comparison. Do not fix what is not a problem. It will be better if: "I got a problem, this part of script is executing very slow, this is my code, can you give advise for this?"

Comment: Read [Eric Lippert's Performance Rant](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) for _why_ this is likely getting downvoted.

Comment: @Fendy. with all due respect I disagree with your stmt "Do not fix what is not a problem". Sometimes we just want to know what others think to improve oneself. Isn't that what this is about? Discussion?

Comment: @JohnRyann From the point of view of "performance", the question as asked indicates a lack of even basic preliminary investigation. As with most "does this trivial syntax change perform better?"-style questions, I suspect there is no performance problem worth worrying about. From the point of view of "best practice" (which is subjective to begin with), the answers you've received concerning readability are pretty obvious. If you've spent enough time with the language to be able to formulate the alternatives you have, it's a question you're capable of answering for yourself. IMO.

Comment: @JohnRyann Ok maybe I need to clarify my statement. It should be: Do not fix what is not a problem, or what is not likely will be a problem. If you script has potential of performance problem (like processing 100k record, etc, etc), then it will be great to discuss. There also a phrase: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". N.B: I didn't downvote this question though, just try to clarify things

Comment: And no, [it isn't about discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). This might be a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one would have to look at the value of `process_checking` twice, so performance would be (very very negligibly) worse. And of course your assumption about the "0" and "1", the first one has to check for "1", which is a little extra work.

The real difference is readability. The second one is much more readable - it's very clear what you're doing, and that if `process_checking` is not true, the entire block gets skipped.

As long as you're not nesting too deep, a little bit of nesting is definitely preferred when it adds to readability.

Comment: I agree, but I'd add that it's possible that the compiler will optimize away that second check of `process_checking` in the first example. (Not that that would excuse its poor readability.) Someone much less lazy than I am could even try it, examine the MISL output, and let us all know the result. :)

Comment: @dgvid Good call, didn't think about that - the optimizer does find creative ways to help with stuff like that. But I also don't really feel like cracking open an IL disassembler to try it out. :)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the second version is better, because you do not repeat the `process_checking` condition. It is more readable, because the control flow is more recongnizable and understandable, and it might be very slightly more performant, because you do not need to recompute the `process_checking` if the first `if` clause fails. However, this is just my opinion; others may have differing views...

Answer (score 1):

The second instance is superior because it only does the process_checking comparison once. And since you say that there is only a 0 or 1 (the input has already been validated, which I assume is what your process_checking flag is for), it does not call the .Contains method twice and thus saves another function call and comparison.

Another neat thing you can do with boolean variables such as process_checking is to have it be the only part of that condition, like you have done with the .Contains method:

```
if (process_checking) 
{
    if (standard_output.Contains("0")) { /*stuff*/ }
    else { /*other stuff*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a combination of both will give better result, because, sometimes you address only two or three options, then you use `if`, `else if` and for more general, often use `if` with `else`, the better idea would be

```
if(condition = true)
{
// statements
}
else if(other condition = true)
{
// statements
}
else
{
// for all general options, which you have'nt addressed
}
```